# How to create MultiIndex from joined MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas

I’ve been trying to wrangle some data from a group of MySQL tables into a Pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex. The tables are roughly like this:

```
create table team (
  teamID           integer        NOT NULL,
  teamName         varchar(64)    NOT NULL,
  primary key      (teamID));

create table coach (
  coachID          integer        NOT NULL,
  teamID           integer        NOT NULL,
  coachName        varchar(64)    NOT NULL,
  primary key      (coachID));

create table player (
  playerID         integer        NOT NULL,
  teamID           integer        NOT NULL,
  playerName       varchar(64)    NOT NULL,
  primary key      (playerID));
```

Each team can have one or more coaches and one or more players.

Here’s the SELECT and MERGE:

```
import mysql.connector
connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', passwd='temp', database='mydb')
team =    sql.read_frame('select * from team;',   connection)
coach =   sql.read_frame('select * from coach;',  connection)
player =  sql.read_frame('select * from player;', connection)
connection.close()

df = pd.merge(
        pd.merge(team, coach,     on='teamID'),
        player,                   on='teamID')
```

The DataFrame now looks like this:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
    teamID teamName  coachID         coachName  playerID      playerName
0        1      Red        1      Rachel Evans         1       Carol Lee
1        1      Red        1      Rachel Evans         2  Abigail O'Neil
2        1      Red        1      Rachel Evans         3      Becky Hood
3        1      Red        1      Rachel Evans         4  Bridget Sawyer
4        1      Red        2       Gladys Nenn         1       Carol Lee
5        1      Red        2       Gladys Nenn         2  Abigail O'Neil
6        1      Red        2       Gladys Nenn         3      Becky Hood
7        1      Red        2       Gladys Nenn         4  Bridget Sawyer
8        2    Green        3     Reina Stevens         5        Amy Reid
9        2    Green        3     Reina Stevens         6     Angie Costa
10       2    Green        3     Reina Stevens         7     Annie Reese
11       2    Green        3     Reina Stevens         8      Barbara Lo
12       2    Green        4         Jill Hunt         5        Amy Reid
13       2    Green        4         Jill Hunt         6     Angie Costa
14       2    Green        4         Jill Hunt         7     Annie Reese
15       2    Green        4         Jill Hunt         8      Barbara Lo
16       3     Blue        5       Lynn Peters         9    Alicia Green
17       3     Blue        5       Lynn Peters        10      Beth Spire
18       3     Blue        5       Lynn Peters        11  Candace Pierce
19       3     Blue        5       Lynn Peters        12    Carmen Jones
20       3     Blue        6  Stephanie Lenter         9    Alicia Green
21       3     Blue        6  Stephanie Lenter        10      Beth Spire
22       3     Blue        6  Stephanie Lenter        11  Candace Pierce
23       3     Blue        6  Stephanie Lenter        12    Carmen Jones
```

And now I would like to create a MultiIndex that shapes this data so that it looks something like this:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
teamID teamName  coachID  coachName  playerID      playerName
    1  Red        1      Rachel Evans    1       Carol Lee
                  2      Gladys Nenn     2       Abigail O'Neil
                                         3       Becky Hood
                                         4       Bridget Sawyer
    2  Green      3      Reina Stevens   5       Amy Reid
                  4      Jill Hunt       6       Angie Costa
                                         7       Annie Reese
                                         8       Barbara Lo
```

I’ve been able to do this with straight Python, but I want to be able to take advantage of Pandas powerful and concise indexing features.

Adding the following

```
df.set_index(['teamID', 'teamName', 'coachID', 'coachName', 'playerID'], inplace=True)
```

makes the first four columns hierarchical. But the last two columns are still duplicated:

```
                                                       playerName
teamID teamName coachID coachName        playerID                
1      Red      1       Rachel Evans     1              Carol Lee
                                         2         Abigail O'Neil
                                         3             Becky Hood
                                         4         Bridget Sawyer
                2       Gladys Nenn      1              Carol Lee
                                         2         Abigail O'Neil
                                         3             Becky Hood
                                         4         Bridget Sawyer
2      Green    3       Reina Stevens    5               Amy Reid
                                         6            Angie Costa
                                         7            Annie Reese
                                         8             Barbara Lo
                4       Jill Hunt        5               Amy Reid
                                         6            Angie Costa
                                         7            Annie Reese
                                         8             Barbara Lo
```

Comment: on your first frame df.set_index(['teamID', 'teamName', 'coachID', 'coachName', 'playerID'])

Comment: I tried that and it seems to have no effect. When I display the DataFrame in ipython (In [2]: df) it displays the same list as above without the benefit of the hierarchical index.

Comment: By default set_index does not happen in place. This means that the operation returns a new object. So the frame on which set_index was executed still is the same. Either you do df = df.set_index(...) or df.set_index(..., inplace=True)

Comment: Thanks. inplace=True works as you say. Now the first four columns are hierarchical and the last two still contain duplicates. Please see above.

Comment: Due to your initial merge operations and multiple coaches per team there is indeed duplication of the playerID/Name, this has nothing to do with hierarchical indexing.